# How to handle missing data for prediction with small data set

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data

I have to analyse the results of american football players. The goal is to predict the position group based on the results of about 20 exercises. Therefore I use SVM, Neural Network, Decision Tree, Naive Bayes and Random Forest and compare the results. I have about 400 samples from 40 players in total. E.g. a player can measure his exercise results multiple times.

The Problem:
Some players leave some exercises out so that the row contains a 0 as result.
If so, I have 2 options:

1.If the player measured the result of the specific exercise at least 1 time I calculate the mean and use it to replace the 0.

2.The player has never measured a single result for the specific exercise. That means I cannot calculate a mean value.
Unfortunately this happens quite often. If I would drop these players I would lose 75% of my data because only 15 players measured their results for all exercises.
Should I use the overall mean (including all players) or leave them 0 so that the data lose their significance and are not considered by the algorithm?

```
playerNo   exercise1    exercise2    exercise3   positionGroup  

1          10.3         44           5.8         1
2          9            62           5.2         2
3          12           33           6.2         1
4          0            35           4.7         3
5          0            46           7.4         2
2          0            55           8.3         2
3          9            41           6.4         1
...
```

Comment: What about, e.g. multiple imputation as option 3. That would more sensibly take into account that people with poor performance on other similar (i.e. highly correlated) excercises would also be expected to perform less well (rather than like the average of other people).

Comment: Your sample size is 40. Maybe it's just me, but I think that's a bit small for the machine learning methods you are using. Machines are dumb. They need lots of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Björn's suggestion, doing multiple imputation would be the best way to approach this. I would perhaps use a distribution based on highly correlated exercises to draw samples, but I wouldn't assume that they skipped it only because they would perform poorly in general -i.e. if they left the exercise until last and then they decided not to do it because they're tired, it doesn't mean that they would in general perform poorly.

You should still run some models excluding variables that have a lot of missing data and compare how they perform to the imputed models. If the model with the variable removed yields better results this may be an indication that it's not a significant variable in the first place.